# How to detect when a user enters an invalid location to a Google Places field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a form that contains a text field that is connected to the Google Places API.  What I want to happen is that, when a recognized address is entered, I also get the lat/long location of the entered place and bash the values into other form fields, so that they can be saved on the backend without another API call.  The following initialization code, along with a few debugging logs, is working fine for this (apologies for the stupid field IDs; I blame Drupal...)

```
    function placesInitialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('edit-field-google-location-und-0-value');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('edit-field-google-location-und-0-value').value;

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                console.log('inside geocoder.geocode');
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    console.log('lat and long = ' + latitude + ' and ' + longitude);
                    $('#edit-field-location-latitude-und-0-value').val(latitude);
                    $('#edit-field-location-longitude-und-0-value').val(longitude);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('GeocoderStatus not ok:');
                    console.log(google.maps.GeocoderStatus);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', placesInitialize);
```

Now, if the user enters something that is not recognized by Places, I want to clear the lat and long fields.  That's where my problem is: how do I detect that this has happened?  I had thought that this would have been signaled by `google.maps.GeocoderStatus` being not OK, but those logs never fire.  In fact, the "inside geocoder.geocode" message doesn't show up in this situation, either.

I've looked, but haven't yet found an event that google.maps might throw in this situation.  I could hang something off the input field's `blur` event, but I'm not sure what it would do (there would be stuff in the input field, just not valid stuff).  I thought about having a semaphor that tracks whether the geocoder has been invoked, but I'd still need to detect the "invalid entry" state to catch the case where the user first enters something valid and then replaces it with something invalid.

Anyway: Any thoughts out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Really? A drive-by down vote?  If there's something wrong with this post, would someone clue me in?  Because I really don't see it...

Answer (score 0):

`place_changed` is still fired even when a suggested location is not selected and "free text" is given. If there is no place found in the geocoder, then the `place.address_components` will be empty and you can detect that:

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 

    if(!place.address_components) {
       // then place doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`place_change` only fires when a user selects one of the suggestions in the dropdown. When the places-library doesn't return suggestions, nothing will happen.

As the Autocomplete doesn't provide access to the the suggestions at all(unless you select one), you may request the suggestions via the [Autocomplete-Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service)(then  you'll be able to check if there are any suggestions).

The Autocomplete-functionality you may implement then on your own based on the returned suggestions(e.g. via jQueryUI)